# Upgrading Mono from 3.6 to the latest version Ubuntu 16.04LTS

Tags: ubuntu, mono, software-updates

I'm having trouble getting to the latest version of mono.
The procedure tried so far:

```
simon@Core2duo:~$ mono -V
Mono JIT compiler version 3.6.0 (tarball Thu Jul 23 23:54:20 EDT 2015)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
    TLS:           __thread
    SIGSEGV:       altstack
    Notifications: epoll
    Architecture:  amd64
    Disabled:      none
    Misc:          softdebug 
    LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
    GC:            sgen

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install mono-complete

sudo apt-get install monodevelop
```

Reboot

```
simon@Core2duo:~$ mono -V
Mono JIT compiler version 3.6.0 (tarball Thu Jul 23 23:54:20 EDT 2015)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
    TLS:           __thread
    SIGSEGV:       altstack
    Notifications: epoll
    Architecture:  amd64
    Disabled:      none
    Misc:          softdebug 
    LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
    GC:            sgen
```

Clearly there is something simple not being done. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you run `apt-get upgrade` after `apt-get update`?

Comment: No I hadn't. Just did.. quite a few things got modified but the same result. Should I remove the old version re download the latest and clean install.. Sounds unnecessary but would perhaps solve the problem. The only problem I have is sonarr is complaining of an unsupported version of Mono.